# Make arara ignore \includeonly command

Tags: include, arara

I'm actually about to write up my dissertation and have split it into chapters that are included into the main document via `\include{chapter}`. To keep compilation times short while working on it, I use `\includeonly{...}` to compile only the chapter I'm actually working on and normally only compile with `pdflatex`.

For the "full" compilation including `biber` and `makeglossaries` (which I omitted in the MWE below) I use `arara` and every now and then I would like to compile the whole document with all chapters. Of course I could just comment the `\includeonly` command, launch `arara` and uncomment `\includeonly` afterwards, but that's a boring solution. Therefore I was asking myself, if there's a way to somehow tell `arara` to ignore the `\includeonly` directive and just compile the whole document. I tried to read the `arara` manual and some questions here on Stackexchange but did not really find a good point to start with.

```
% arara: pdflatex: { synctex: yes}

\begin{filecontents}{chapter1.tex}
     Some text
\end{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{chapter2.tex}
    Another text
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{book}

\includeonly{chapter1}

\begin{document}
\include{chapter1}
\include{chapter2}
\end{document}
```

Comment: not sure about arara (don't tell Paulo:-) but if you can make it do a commandline of `\def\includeonly#1{}\input mainfile` then `\includeonly` will be disabled.